# Hot reload in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, hot-reload

Is there a way to enable hot reload (changing the page content without reloading the whole app) in Ember 4.2?

I tried plugins such as ember-ast-hot-load but I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's baked in. Just run `ember serve` at the terminal/command prompt. If you are using another web server such as IIS or Apache you can use `ember build --watch` (or `ember build -w`) to rebuild the site whenever you change the source code but you will need to reload the page manually.